# Отсортируйте массив по нескольким условиям

Tags: сортировка, любой-язык, соревнование

Вход: массив целых чисел(`-2^31 <= n < 2^31`)

Выход: массив чисел отсортированный в следующем порядке:

- неотрицательные четные
- отрицательные нечетные
- неотрицательные нечетные
- отрицательные четные

Если несколько чисел попадёт в одну группу, то отсортировать их по возрастанию

Это code golf, но ни один ответ не будет принят т.к. цель вопрос в том чтобы собрать короткое решение на каждом языке

пожалуйста используйте сайт https://tio.run/ чтобы можно было легко запускать ваш код

---

```
Вход:
[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Выход:
[0, 2, 4, -5, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, -4, -2]
```

---

Таблица лидеров:

```js
execute("ru.stackoverflow.com", "1236112");
```

```css
.cssload-container,.cssload-cube{width:97px;height:97px;transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container,.cssload-cube,.cssload-half1,.cssload-half2{transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container{position:relative;margin:23px 84px;perspective:292px}.cssload-cube{animation:cube 11.5s forwards infinite;transform-origin:center 49px}.cssload-half1,.cssload-s1{top:0;transform-origin:50% 100%}.cssload-half1{height:39px;position:absolute;animation:half-fold 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-side{width:19px;height:19px;background:#ddd;position:absolute}.cssload-s1{left:39px;animation:s1ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s2,.cssload-s3,.cssload-s4{left:39px;transform-origin:50% 0}.cssload-s2{top:19px;animation:s2ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s3{top:39px;animation:s3ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s4{top:58px;animation:s4ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s5{left:19px;top:19px;transform-origin:100% 50%;animation:s5ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s6{left:58px;top:39px;transform-origin:0 50%;animation:s6ani 11.5s forwards infinite}@keyframes cube{0%,30%{transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}60%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}65%,70%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(180deg)}75%,80%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(1turn)}90%{transform:rotateX(0) rotate(0) rotate(0)}}@keyframes s1ani{0%{opacity:1;transform:translateY(0);background:#ddd}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(-90deg);background:#ddd}90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}@keyframes s2ani{0%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%,80%{background:#b4b4b4}65%{opacity:1;background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s3ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}20%,90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%{background:#969696}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s4ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%,to{opacity:0}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(90deg);background:#b4b4b4}80%{background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(90deg)}}@keyframes s5ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(-179deg)}20%{opacity:1;background:#ddd;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(90deg)}55%{background:#ddd}60%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{transform:rotateY(90deg);opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s6ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(179deg)}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(-90deg);background:#ddd}60%,80%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(-90deg)}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes half-fold{0%,50%{transform:rotateX(0)}60%,90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}
```

```html
<script src="https://mayorovp.github.io/codegolf/table-8c505e68f1349e4c69e7.js"></script>
<div class=cssload-container><div class=cssload-cube><div class=cssload-half1><div class="cssload-side cssload-s1"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s2"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s5"></div></div><div class=cssload-half2><div class="cssload-side cssload-s3"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s4"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s6"></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: @EOF зачем вы удалили свой ответ?

Comment: А что - ещё и за размер кода тоже битва идёт? И как-то странно с этими лямбдами...

Comment: @CrazyElf Да! цель code golf самый короткий код :)

Comment: Что-то не очень активно в этот раз проходит соревнование

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл согласен. Предлагаю вам опубликовать ответ для увеличения активности!

Answer (score 9):

## Pyth, 18

```
o(+*2x%N2J>ZNJ N)Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P19DW8uoQtXPyMsuys9LwU8z8P//aF1THQVdEyA2BmIjIDbUUTDQUQCSQA5QDChlGgsA)

Перевод:

```
o                    #1 Сортировка значения из стека(#9) по ключу (с lambda N:)
 (                   #2 Ключ будет кортежем (из 2 элементов)
   +                 #3 Сложение 2 элементов из стека (#4 + #7)
    *2               #4 стек(#5) * 2
      x %N2          #5 стек(#6) XOR N % 2
        J>ZN         #6 кладем в стек (0 > N) и запоминаем его же в переменной J
    J                #7 Только что сохраненная (в стр#6) J идет в стек для сложения (стр#3)
  N                  #8 Второй элемент кортежа, текущий элемент массива
 )Q                  #9 Конец кортежа и помещение входного массива в стек
```

Алгоритм примерно тот же, что применен в perl варианте, считаем первый ключ сортировки по формуле:

```
J = (N < 0)
((N % 2) ^ J) * 2 + J
```

Comment: `o(+*2x%N2J>ZNJ N)Q`  — ничего не понятно, но очень интересно :)

Answer (score 8):

## perl, 56

Не люблю поддерживать миф, что perl самый непонятный язык, но ...

```
$,=", ";
@X = (-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
print sort{($a<0^$a&1).($a<0)cmp($b<0^$b&1).($b<0)||$a<=>$b}@X;
```

Функция sort сортирует указанный в самом конце массив (`@X`) с помощью блока кода перед ним. В этом блоке доступны предопределенные переменные `$a` и `$b` содержащие сравниваемые значения. задача блока вычислить какое из них больше.

```
sort {
    Выражение1 cmp Выражение2   # Лексикографическое сравнение двух выражений
    ||                          # ИЛИ (если они равны)
    $a <=> $b                   # Числовое сравнение самих переменных
} @X;
```

Теперь само выражение для оценки веса переменной:

```
( $a<0 ^ $a & 1 )   # XOR между значениями признака отрицательного числа и его четности (младшего бита)
                    # он равен 0 для неотрицательных четных и отрицательных нечетных, иначе 1
.                   # Конкатенация строк
( $a<0 )            # признак отрицательности
                    # в perl сравнение дает пустую строку если условие ложно или 1 если истинно
```

На выходе данное выражение дает строки: "0", "01", "1", "11". В лексикографическом порядке эти строки дают нужный нам порядок условий.

Пример на [tio.run](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19Fx1ZJR0HJmsshQsFWQUPXVEdB1wSIjYHYCIgNdRQMdBSAJJADFANKmWpacxUUZeaVKBTnF5UoVGuoJNoYxKkkqhlq6oHZmsm5BRoqSSDBJIggkK1ZUwOUs7VTSapVcIiw/v8fAA)

Comment: Хороший ответ. Мне кажется лучше реализовать через функцию и передавать туда массив, а вызов функции с выводом засунуть в `Footer`

Comment: @Danis Я думал над функцией, мне показалось что длиннее выйдет. Но надо попробовать все таки ...

Comment: @Danis попробовал функцию `sub S{pop;($_<0^$_&1).($_<0)}sort{S$a cmp S$b||$a<=>$b}@X` на 1 символ длиннее вышло :) Хотя вы говорили про оформление всего кода как функции. Ну да, можно для красоты конечно. хотя какая тут красота если фиг прочитаешь :)

Comment: я думал что Вы создания массив и вывод массива посчитали, но вы этого не сделали так что все хорошо

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3, 55

```python
lambda a:sorted(a,key=lambda x:('1342'[(x<0)*2+x%2],x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHRqji/qCQ1RSNRJzu10hYqWmGloW5obGKkHq1RYWOgqWWkXaFqFKtToan5P1HBViFa11RHQdcEiI2B2AiIDXUUDHQUgCSQAxQDSpnGchUUZeaVaKRpJAK1AQA)

Ну вот `Python`, хотя какое-то шаманство получилось, наверняка можно формулу пересчёта весов для сортировки критериев вывести, но у меня пока не получилось:

```python
a = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(sorted(a, key=lambda x: ([[1, 3], [4, 2]][x < 0][x % 2], x)))
```

Вывод:

```python
[0, 2, 4, -5, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, -4, -2]
```

Краткое (или не очень) разъяснение:

- `sorted` - стандартная функция для сортировки коллекций в `Python`, в данном случае использован вариант с заданием нестандартного ключа сортировки с помощью именованного параметра `key=`
- `lambda x:` - способ описания *анонимных функций* в `Python`
- Сортировать в питоне можно по составному ключу, для этого в качестве ключа сортировки указывается кортеж, в данном случае использован кортеж `(хитрое условие по числу, само число)`
- Для выборки нужного веса сортировки используется индексация в двумерном списке (можно воспринимать как матрицу) `[[значения],[значения]][строка][столбец]`
- Кроме того, при выполнении индексации тут используется тот факт, что булевы значения могут использоваться как целые числа: `True` - это `1`, а `False` - это `0`

Comment: Можно убрать лишние пробелы, x%2==1 заменить на x%2.

Comment: @КириллМалышев Про сравнение согласен, спасибо! А пробелов, думаю, даже мало, я всегда ставлю промежуточные пробелы, отделяя переменные от остального контекста.

Comment: `lambda a:sorted(a,key=lambda x:(['13','42'][x<0][x%2],x))`  57

Comment: @Mike О, спасибо! Я ещё на 2 байта ваш код сократил ))

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (V8), 50

(Способ №3)

```
v=>v.sort((a,b,t=x=>x*2&2|x<0||4)=>t(b)-t(a)||a-b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnBCoMwEATQu1@RU9ktSbCpgmCTHyk9JKJFEVM0LDnk39M9vIGZ2Tz5azrXX1I01MVWso70Fc8E4GWQyWbr8t3cTMmvtpQOrUsQUCXwWIpXAes@J0HCirfqpVAdezLDHlK0UnBy4Y2v/jM2CxCOzRSPK@6z3uMXSG9xPQBxrH8)

```js
let v = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
v.sort((a,b,t=x=>x*2&2|x<0||4)=>t(b)-t(a)||a-b);
console.log(v.join());
```

---

[JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 52 bytes (Способ №2)

```
v=>v.sort((a,b)=>(b*2&2|b<0||4)-(a*2&2|a<0||4)||a-b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYlBCoMwEEX3nmJWZVKSYFMFIY0XKV0kokUJpmiYVe6eDu3ifXjvb578OR3rJysa6uIquZH0mY6M6GUQbsRwNRdTwqMtpRMK/U/9X0vxKoga5wwEDp6ql6A65s4Y5iahlcDLwo2v/mWbBUnYZkr7meKsY3oj6S2tOwph6xc)

```js
let v = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
v.sort((a,b)=>(b*2&2|b<0||4)-(a*2&2|a<0||4)||a-b);
console.log(v.join());
```

---

[JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 62 bytes (Способ №1)

```javascript
v=>v.sort((a,b)=>"0231"[(a<0)*2|a&1]-"0231"[(b<0)*2|b&1]||a-b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYlBCsIwEEX3PcXQhSSSlCa1IGh6kdLFpLSiBCNNmFXuHgfExfvw3n8hYVqP5ydrutbdVXITdSkeWQhUXrqp7e1g2lngvZdnW/BkFv1v/tc8t1JQe1nDloHAwaxHBfrCDIxljIJeAS8LN77G5dbsgmSzxneKYetCfLDWLw)

```js
let v = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
v.sort((a,b)=>"0231"[(a<0)*2|a&1]-"0231"[(b<0)*2|b&1]||a-b);
console.log(v.join());
```

Comment: `0231` в переменную если сложить. то 4 байта сэкономить можно?

Comment: @teran, только 1. Накладные расходы на переменную будут 4, а потом 6 заменится на 1: `..."0231"[...]-"0231"[...]` => `...(x="0231")[...]-x[...]`. По крайней мере, я не вижу более хорошего способа запихать в эту конструкцию переменную. Хм.. Хотя, если объявлять не в функции, а заранее, то можно добавить `x=;`, перенести одну строку, убрать вторую и вставить ещё два раза `x` - получится +3-6+2 = -1 опять. И ещё способ сделать тот же -1 - это пихать в сам sort: `sort((a,b,x="0231")=>x[...]`.

Answer (score 5):

## C#, 47 bytes

Минус 10 байт, если не требовать на выходе массив.

Хоть C# и не предназначен для гольфа, вот вам версия на C# (48 байт):

```
a=a.OrderBy(v=>((v<0?1:0)^v&1,v<0,v)).ToArray();
```

Проверка [тут](https://tio.run/##LY7BCsIwEETvfsXiQRJIQqr2Yq2i3kTwoOBBKoQaJKAJbmKkiN9e9yDsW5idgZ02yja6/hWdv8Ghi8k@1M75ZzXIBsFADd6@zw18QJYC5JSYEGOiEKAF0CZBN7JK@Fa9qY3a49XiumO5XjCW53pZzDS/5FEhSIjMuTqGFaLpGK/6/9dN8DHcrTqhS5YqWBYTUiu1Dc6zoQAawyn/Aw).

Идея та же, что и в ответе @Mike: сортировка по sign bit ^ parity bit, потом по sign bit, потом по значению.

Более изящное решение с заменой `v<0,v` на `(uint)v`, к сожалению, проигрывает по размеру.

---

Выиграл ещё байт, заменив приведение к интам на приведение к bool:

```
a=a.OrderBy(v=>(v<0^(v&1)==1,v<0,v)).ToArray();
```

Проверка [тут](https://tio.run/##LY5BCwIhEIXv/YqhQyi4slZ7MoPqFkGHgg5RILsSQimNmyHRb9/mEMw38OY9mNemqk1@eCUfbnAoqXcPufPhqUfZIlgwENz7fIEPVI2Aak7MiCmhBNQCaJOgG1kNfPVgjZV77ByuC8tmyfKivrI8UdwYJUiIzLk8xhWiLYzr4f90E0OKdydP6HtHDRxLPVIpuY0@sLEAGssp/wM).

Comment: @Danis Почему самое короткое, Haskell в ответе extrn явно лаконичнее

Comment: @Mike: Ну если убрать ToArray (Хаскель вроде бы ленивый, так что там нету ToArray по сути), то выйдет 37 байт, не сильно хуже Хаскеля.

Comment: @VladD, а что именно здесь из 9-ой версии?

Comment: @4per: Хм, первоначальная версия была на 9-ом, но сейчас скомпилируется и старыми версиями. Спасибо за подсказку! Поменял ссылки.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 34 bytes

```
f=sortOn(\x->(odd x/=(x<0),x<0,x))
```

Сортировка по трем характеристикам

- Число исключительно отрицательное или нечетное? (сначала четные неотрицательные и нечетные отрицательные)
- Отрицательное ли число? (сначала неотрицательные)
- Значение числа

Требуется импорт `Data.List`

Можно использовать без имени функции, тогда -2 байта

```
main = print (sortOn(\x->(odd x/=(x<0),x<0,x)) [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYs9DgIhGER7TzElJKDrz3ZiZWniAdTiS9iNRBY2CwW3xyneJPMm85Xym2LsYVnzVnGXKvtHKLXPrlA8k3o3e1PZe7SDU@06aMMwTeu@SEhw8HkHxKlCWF52NLAXciYncjQYDJgsdJzGDw/rFlKFmiG6/wE)

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 122 bytes

```php
$x=[[],[],[],[]];
foreach($d as $v)$x[$v>=0?($v%2?2:0):($v%2?1:3)][]=$v;
foreach($x as $v)sort($v);
$r=array_merge(...$x);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzdCsIwDIXv@xRBIqzQjf24m9VuD1KKlFnthbLRyZiIz17jL0JOyEnOl9GPcduNfmQM96BAp7WAdEOqSCWpEJALoE6GdnSqjYy4KK2N@JaR7DAEZ3uf0Bs7Ac4cF41zq/IuwXlddmWT8@Y9Fk3FjTYK5z9s@WDTEC4U45JhUDYEe92dXTi6JMsyXLiMPyK8CHfiNwbgej88jYAVrCS7A2NdGx8)

нормальная версия кода:

```php
$d = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$x = [[],[],[],[]];
foreach($d as $v){
    $i = $v >= 0 ? ( $v%2 ? 2 : 0) : ( $v%2 ? 1 : 3 );
    $x[$i][] = $v;
}
foreach($x as $v) sort($v);
$r = array_merge(...$x);
```

Comment: сча чутка попробую уменьшить еще

Comment: я попытался добавить ваш код в tio.run но кажется сделал что-то не так. пожалуйста поправьте код по ссылке и вставьте его в вопрос https://tio.run/##RY3dCsIgFIDv9xRenEDBiXPtRrE9iEhIWdtFbLgQI3p2O1ARnO9w/vjOOq0VzsQS1w6ctHukRxTScSI5wYwNznA1eFOhWOc8/4U3zWVJMZwmipqwEcjsCbOFfLBypJB3alRaMv0pO90zA8XB7J3Hr5DN6y8oX8G2pDveM9NAsiGl8DjeYrpGKoSAwkytbw

Comment: что-то сюда бы как-то приделать оператор `<=>`, но идей, которые сократили бы код, особых нет.

Comment: https://tio.run/##TUzRCoJAEHzfr1hkA41T1PLF0@5DjiPEru6h8DhDjOjbbSWKYGd3Z2dmvfNLo7zzAHTCFnVaCUz3jB2jZBQCc4HcmfCNpcrIheZWayO@ZSSch2C73sX8phtpSmjWNDW5omlTqqLe1euyLY02LU1/9vljH4dwj3lKoNB2IXSP482Gi42zLKM5kcsvEDiAZK/JExBt74aVCIwwkvBCAHVY3g

Answer (score 3):

## Powershell 7.1

```
(@(-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) | Sort-Object -Property `
    @{Expression={$_ -ge 0 -and $_ % 2 -eq 0}; Descending=$true}, `
    @{Expression={$_ -lt 0 -and $_ % 2 -ne 0}; Descending=$true}, ` 
    @{Expression={$_ -gt 0 -and $_ % 2 -ne 0}; Descending=$true}, `
    @{Expression={$_ -le 0 -and $_ % 2 -eq 0}; Descending=$true}) -join ", "
```

подумал получше

```
(((-5..5).Where({$_ -lt 0}, 5)).foreach{$_.Where({$_ % 2}, 5)})[3,0,2,1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f9fQ0ND11RPz1RTLzwjtShVo1olXkE3p0TBoFZHwVRTUy8NqCoxOQMojKRAVcEILF2rGW2sY6BjpGMY@/8/AA)

Comment: добавьте пожалуйста ссылку на https://tio.run/

Answer (score 2):

**С/C++**

За краткостью не гнался.

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ wc srt.c
 30 145 827 srt.c
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```

Код проверил на https://tio.run/# в gcc и clang как C и C++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmpf (const void *p, const void *q) {
  static int sort_key[4] = {
    0, // неотрицательные четные    'b00
    2, // неотрицательные нечетные  'b01
    3, // отрицательные четные      'b10
    1  // отрицательные нечетные    'b11
  };
  int v1 = *(int *)p, v2 = *(int *)q;
  int type1 = ((v1 < 0) << 1) | (v1 & 1),
    type2 = ((v2 < 0) << 1) | (v2 & 1);

  return type1 != type2 ?  sort_key[type1] - sort_key[type2] :
     v1 < v2 ? -1 : v1 == v2 ? 0 : 1;
}

int main ()
{
  int a[] = {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  size_t n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

  qsort(a, n, sizeof(a[0]), cmpf);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d%s", a[i], i == n - 1? "\n" : ", ");

  return 0;
}
```

Идея компаратора состоит в том, что мы формируем 2-х разрядное число, состоящее из знака и бита четности, которое используем как индекс в массиве ключа сортировки.